# Сравнение элементов списков и сортировка списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for

Есть список списков arr. В каждом из вложенных списков есть `n` элементов. Если в списке второй элемент больше, чем первый, третий больше, чем второй, и так далее, его нужно добавить в отдельный список. Я попытался сделать это с помощью булевой переменной, но не получилось. Вот код:

```
arr = [[6, 8], [3, 8, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
b = []
for i in range(0, len(arr):
    g = False
    for h in range(0, len(arr[i] - 1)):
        if g == True and h == len(arr[i]) - 2):
            b.append()
        if arr[i[h]] < arr[i[h+1]]:
            g = True
print(b)
```

Comment: Еще раз, нужно добавить в b все отсортированные по возрастанию массивы из arr?

Comment: А вы можете дать начало этого кода? Откуда у вас берутся a, c, h и какое они имеют значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def is_sorted(sequence) -> bool:  # Создаём функцию, определяющую, отсортирована ли последовательность
    it = iter(sequence)  # Создаём итератор по последовательности

    try:  
        lhs = next(it)  # Получаем первый элемент последовательности
    except StopIteration:  # Если исходная последовательность пустая
        raise ValueError('Empty sequence')  # Возбуждаем соответствующее исключение

    for rhs in it:  # Перебираем оставшиеся элементы последовательности
        if lhs < rhs:  # Если очередной элемент больше предыдущего
            lhs = rhs  # Запоминаем его для дальнейшего сравнения уже с ним
        else:
            return False  # Иначе возвращаем False - последовательность не отсортирована
    return True  # Если return False не сработал, значит, последовательность отсортирована, возвращаем True


arr = [[6, 8], [3, 8, 3], [3, 4, 5]]  # Входные данные

# Фильтруем arr по критерию "отсортирован",
#  результат приводим к списку и сохраняем в другую переменную
b = list(filter(is_sorted, arr))
```

Comment: Почти правильно, но при входных значениях типа [5, 5, 7], [1, 4, 4] где одно число идёт подряд два раза, срабатывает неправильно, помещая их в список с правильными решениями.

Comment: @Zollex Вы правы, упустил условие *второй элемент больше, чем первый, третий больше, чем второй*. Отредактировал.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за помощь и отзывчивость. Хорошего дня!! До свидания.

Answer (score 2):

Как то так:

```
arr = [[6, 8], [3, 8, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
b = []

for mas in arr:
    is_ordered = True
    for i in range(1, len(mas)):
        if mas[i] < mas[i-1]: # заменить условие < на условие <=  
            is_ordered = False
            break
        is_ordered = is_ordered and (mas[i] > mas[i-1]) # убрать эту строку!
    if is_ordered:
        b.append(mas)
print(b)
```

Comment: Вообще, я согласен, но зачем строка `is_ordered = is_ordered and (mas[i] > mas[i-1])`? Вам стоит заменить в условии перед ней < на <=, и тогда данная строка вообще будет не нужна.

Comment: @EzikBro ваша правда! :) уже полвторого ночи. Голова медленнее думает. :)  Безусловно именно так всё как вы написали - оптимально.